# Computed time column in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Using vs2008 I have a SQL Server database attached to my web app. I want to use a computed time column in the database, along the lines of :

- timenow is 1 column
- hoursleft is another column
- timeend would be another column.

I want timeend to = timenow + hoursleft.

Is it possible to do that, and if so what would the formula be that I would enter into the computed column field, and, what datatype would the columns be, timenow and timeend I would expect to be time(7) and hoursleft an int. But is that correct? THanks for any help.

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server?? SQL Server 2008 introduced new datatypes like `TIME` which would be perfect for this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- TimeNow is datatype datetime, populated with function [GetUtcDate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx).
- HoursLeft is an int, populated as required.
- TimeEnd is a computed column of type datetime, computed as [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)(hh, HoursLeft, TimeNow).

Answer (score 0):

You'd use this to calculate timeend from the 2 existing columns hoursleft and timenow

```
CAST(DATEADD(hour, hoursleft, timenow) AS time(7))
```

[DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) return type is

> The return data type is the data type of the date argument

So the explicit CAST probably isn't needed if timenow is time(7) as you mentioned

```
DATEADD(hour, hoursleft, timenow)
```